# Pre Poulate a Text Field with a URL

Tags: mobile, textbox, ios-simulator

I have a mobile simulator at http://businessmobilewebsite.com/tester/ and was wondering if there is a script or way to populate the text field so that I can send a sampole of the customer mobile website to them.

Maybe I need to change it to a php file or something.

So I would like to send them to say

http://businessmobilewebsite.com/tester/?url=http://speedie.mobi/luchetti/#

Quentin

Answer (score 0):

That website uses javascript within the page to load the entered URL within their "emulator" and does support passing parameters as the web page is not a "real" web form.

If you have a specific question about the functionality of a specific website, then why not contact them http://businessmobilewebsite.com/contact/

There are alternative online mobile emulators which do support the funcitonality you require, such as:

http://iphonetester.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fspeedie.mobi%2Fluchetti%2F
or
http://emulator.mtld.mobi/emulator.php?webaddress=speedie.mobi/luchetti/&emulator=sonyK750

Comment: Yes I know of these others but I am trying to build my own and this is as far as my programing knowledge takes me.

Is there anybody who could add functionality for me like triger the view via a website url like 

http://businessmobilewebsite.com/tester/?rl=http://speedie.mobi/luchetti/#

Also retain the url in the text field when swaping pages.

Comment: @Quentin So businessmobilewebsite.com is your site? You build websites but don't know how to take a parameter from the query string and don't know how to populate a field? If that's the case and you're using PHP (as your question indicates) then check out $_GET http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php